# DateTime class and last month

Tags: php, datetime

I have some weird behaviour with DateTime class. 
Today is 2012-05-31. Timezone is "Europe/Vilnius". 
Following code

```
 $date = new DateTime('last month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

outputs `2012-05-01`. Is this a php bug? By the way, `$date = new DateTime('-1 month');` outputs the same.

Comment: `Note that '-1 month' may produce unexpected result when used in last day of month that has 31 days` [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php#102947), seems to be the same for `last month`

Comment: Guess you are right, this behaviour looks like a bug. Check the comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Please report this as a bug. Thx.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This seems to be special case for months with 31 days:

> Note that '-1 month' may produce unexpected result when used in last day of month that has 31 days
>   *<sub>(from http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php#102947)</sub>*

What you can do is:

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of last month'); // this is "2012-04-30" now
/// 'first day of last month' would work either, of course
```

And then it depends on what you are going to do with the date.

Comment: Not unexpected if you know what `-1 month` actually means. That's explained somewhere else, but we're all too lazy to look for the duplicate on this site, aren't we?

Comment: Nah, I am not too lazy, I'm just in lack of time. And anyway, this shouldn't be my responsibility. I am just trying to help :). It seems like this helped

Comment: Hey, I did not say that it's your job. I'm too lazy, too ;)

Comment: Hehe okay, what I meant is, that he/she has to check for duplicates before asking :). But of course we all should be more satisfied and not so lazy!

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to have a datetime that already exist and modify it, like this:

```
<?php
$d = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d") );
$d->modify( 'last day of previous month' );
echo $d->format( 'Y-m-d' ), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code block I hope that it help:

Note today is : 2022-12-05

```
    const MONTH_YEAR_DAY_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d';

 
    $startDate_m = new \DateTimeImmutable("first day of this month");
    $endDate_m = new \DateTimeImmutable("last day");
    $startDate_m_1 = new \DateTimeImmutable("first day of previous month");
    $endDate_m_1 = $endDate_m->modify("-1 month");

    echo  $startDate_m->format(self::MONTH_YEAR_DAY_FORMAT);
    echo  $endDate_m ->format(self::MONTH_YEAR_DAY_FORMAT);
    echo  $startDate_m_1 ->format(self::MONTH_YEAR_DAY_FORMAT);
    echo  $endDate_m_1 ->format(self::MONTH_YEAR_DAY_FORMAT);


// result
// startDate_m:   2022-12-01 
// endDate_m:     2022-12-05 
// startDate_m_1: 2022-11-01 
// endDate_m_1:   2022-12-05
```